# Enabling line-wrap in a docbook programlisting and adding a line wrap symbol

Tags: docbook

We have some programmer's manual where the example source code lines do not fit to an A4 page when converted to PDF.

Since manually line-breaking the code is too much and manual work, I am thinking about enabling line-wrapping for long lines. However to indicate the line wrap a line wrap symbol (e.g. a mini enter symbol )shall be put as the final character.

Is this possible ?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/FittingText.html#BreakLongLines

Comment: Does this still work for Docbook V5 ? (it appears to be a document about Docbook v4)